# Error saying Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

I use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, (RIGHT(b.dob, 4) + '-' +
                       SUBSTRING(b.dob, 3, 2) + '-' +
                       LEFT (b.dob, 2)), 111) 
FROM [Load].[123_Qualification] AS b
```

The `Dob` is a `nvarchar` column, and I want to convert it to a `DateTime` datatype, but I am  getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What's the format of the values in dob?

Comment: Sample data for your nvarchar date format.

Comment: Its in ddmmyyyy format.

Comment: The sample data would look 13051971 i.e in ddmmyyyy format.

Comment: Don't store dates as varchar. Ever.

Comment: Check for any value that len(dob) <> 8 or isnumeric(dob) = 0. You might find a bad record. A bad 8 digit value (eg 12345678) would give you an out-of-range value error instead of a conversion failed.

Comment: @MaxSzczurek: `isnumeric` will return true for something like this as well: `123e32` but even if it didn't, a value like this would pass your test: `44556666`, but still can't be converted to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should change your table to store the dob in a `date` data type column. Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

One way to solve it is to use the built in `ISDATE` function and a CTE:

Create and populate sample table: (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    dob varchar(8)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('23031971'), 
('23131971'),
('12031999'),
('02031980'),
('29021972'),
('29021973'),
('29021974'),
('29021975'),
('31121976')
```

Use a common table expression to format all dob values to `yyyy-mm-dd` (This is a standard format that sql server will recognize regardless of reginal, language and date format settings)

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT (RIGHT(b.dob, 4) + '-' +
            SUBSTRING(b.dob, 3, 2) + '-' +
            LEFT (b.dob, 2)) As formatted_dob
    FROM @T AS b
)
```

Select from the common table expression only those values that represents a valid date. (Note in the sample data there are multiple 29th of february, but only one in the results)

```
SELECT CAST(formatted_dob as DATE) As date_of_birth
FROM CTE
WHERE ISDATE(formatted_dob) = 1
```

Results:

```
date_of_birth
23.03.1971 00:00:00
12.03.1999 00:00:00
02.03.1980 00:00:00
29.02.1972 00:00:00
31.12.1976 00:00:00
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/KRDR82116)

Answer (score 0):

Use STUFF and CONVERT methods :

```
 SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(13051971, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/'),103)
```

Comment: Could you please rewrite  this with my query.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(b.dob, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/'),103) FROM [Load].[123_Qualification] AS b I tried with this but still getiing error

Comment: Its nvarchar field

Comment: For versions 2012 or higher, you better use try_convert.  
Instead of raising an error like convert does, it will simply return null for values it can't convert.